# Remove backslash character from string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I have a file with every zip code in the US and its respective latitude and longitude. The file format is "ZIP/LAT/LNG\n" I am going to save each of those values to a database. So I wrote the following code to test if I could properly split the values:

```
zip_code_file = open('zipcode.rtf')
for s in zip_code_file.read().split(','):
    print(s)
```

But this prints
"00602"
"18.361945"
 "-67.175597\"

How can I remove that '\' from the longitude so I can properly save the number to my database? I tried the following, but it did not work:

```
for s in zip_code_file.read():
    if s == '\\':
        s.replace('\]', '')
    print(s)
```

Comment: what's wrong with just remove it? (remove the last char)

Comment: `s.strip('\\')` ?

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
l=["00602", "18.361945", "-67.175597\\"]
print([i.replace('\\','') for i in l])
```

Output:

```
['00602', '18.361945', '-67.175597']
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
for s in zip_code_file.read(): # ok, you get lines
    if s == '\\':              # if the whole line is equal to \
        s.replace('\]', '')    # replace "\]" (???) with ""
    print(s)
```

Problem:

1. your if condition only works if the *whole* string is \
2. `str.replace()` does return a changed string that you do not keep around, so its discarded

Solution:

```
with open('zipcode.rtf') as zip_code_file:
    lines = zip_code_file.readlines()

lines = [x.strip() for x in lines if x.strip()] # removes whitespaces && empty lines

for l in lines:
    try:
        zipCode,lat,long = l.split(",")  # split on ',' or '/'? your code and Q differ
        long = long.rstrip("\\") # remove trailing \

        # do smth with zipCode,lat,long

    except ValueError as ve:
        print("Value error in line: ", l)
```